# ECHO %VAR% to FILE (Not value of %VAR%, but text "%VAR%")

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command-line, echo

```
%VAR%=VARIABLE
```

I need to echo %VAR% to file so after command:

```
ECHO %VAR% > FILE.TXT
```

content of FILE.TXT will be:

```
%VAR%
```

But since `%VAR%` was defined and assigned value, file will look like

```
VARIABLE
```

What do i need to add to my command to make it echo `%VAR%` and not the value?

Comment: `ECHO %%VAR%% > FILE.TXT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn on local variables and set %var% to blank.

You can also escape it with the caret. `echo ^%var^%`

See `setlocal /?`

Comment: The second method will.

Comment: "echo %%1" and "echo ^%%1" work in batch, is there difference between them?

Comment: Echo %%var%% won't. Usually, but not always, % escapes %. But ^ is the escape key.

Comment: Ya, for variable i use ^ before % and for parameters double %